# C# consuming local web service "unable to connect to remote serevr"

Tags: c#, web-services, localhost

I had built a web service in C# and client app (form) that consumes this web service (using add reference), it works great. But when I closed the project and re-run the client app only. I had the probleme "unable to connect to remote serevr".

My question can I consume the web service without running the server application? if yes, how to do it?

Comment: The service you're consuming should, of course, be running so it can successfully be consumed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You have to host it somewhere in order to be consumed by a client. Actually, that's the nature of a web service. Provided that it is hosted in a server, then you can cosnume it if you have the right credentials and you know how to get and post data to it.